# MongoDB:Get records from collection MongoDB not in array if ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to get random records from a collection which should not contain ids in an array.

What ids in follow array should be excluded

```
let id_arr=[
        "5b8e79f113bd9a0d8a717635","5b8e8b0447bfb114b4858e9d","5b8e9109ee2e6c07765ba023"
      ];
```

How to add conditions to aggragations? like _id:{$nin:id_arr}

```
      let questionQry = await Questions.aggregate([{$match:{_id:{$nin:tearr}}},{$sample: { size:12 }}]);
```

Comment: What is not working ? Have to tried to wrap id inside mongoose objectid type ?

Comment: Your ids should be cast with the `ObjectId`

Comment: I made the same mistake again.! You guys were right thank you . @Veeram